# Airline weekly/monthly passes from Gujarat state to Pune, India

Tags: air-travel, indian-citizens, passenger-rights

I want to know if there exists a monthly/weekly ticket in any of the Airlines operating from Ahmedabad to Pune in India
I want to travel to and from every day.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although I highly doubt how them airline fellows are managing such a thing, but a quick google shows that such a pass does exist : http://www.airindia.com/SBCMS/Webpages/AI-Introduces-Attractive-Ten.aspx